# Xcode Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: ios, xcode, dijkstra

I wanted to use in my app this classes https://github.com/aq1018/digraph
I added a class and copied quick example for testing. I print out the table and get

```
"<GraphNode: 0x7fdbb2443e50>" 
"<GraphNode: 0x7fdbb2669360>"
```

instead of [n3, nt]. What is wrong?

Comment: How do you print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see from the print result, library and the way you print it, looks like you're printing an NSArray that contains GraphNode class.
That's why you're getting this

```
"<GraphNode: 0x7fdbb2443e50>" 
"<GraphNode: 0x7fdbb2669360>"
```

instead of this

```
[n3, nt]
```

if you want to see the result value maybe you can loop through the array and get hash value of the GraphNode like this :

```
for (GraphNode *node in path) {
    NSLog(@"%@",node.value);
}
```

this way you will get the hash value of the node.
I help this can help you, if you have question regarding my answer feel free to ask in the comment!

Comment: This is work: for (GraphNode *node in path) {
        NSLog(@"%@",node.value);
    }

Comment: @WildWorld ah yeah sorry for the * symbol I forgot about it